# Formatting PHP Code within Vim

Tags: php, vim, code-formatting, tidy

I'm currently using Vim as a lightweight IDE. I have NERDTree, bufexplorer, supertab, and ctags plugins which do *almost* everything I want. Only big thing missing for me is auto code formatting.

I'm working with some messy PHP code which has inconsistent indenting and code formatting, ideally I could highlight the code I want formatted (whole files would be fine too) and run a command to tidy it.

Does anybody have a nice solution for this working in Vim?

Comment: I like Wesley Mason's idea using "shift-v" followed by "=". I record the key sequence of "shift-v" and "=" into a macro. Then I call the macro as many times as I want to format multiple lines of code.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Quick way to fix PHP indentation in vim is to visually select the lines you want to work with using <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>, and then press equals (<kbd>=</kbd>) to trigger auto-formatting.

As for other formatting issues you're probably looking at employing some regex search and replaces, such as `:%s/^M/\r/g` (that's <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>m</kbd>, not <kbd>caret</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd>) to fix line endings

Comment: I can't believe I didn't know about equals auto-formatting years ago, that's really useful. For the formatting issues I *could* build some custom regex's, I guess I was hoping someone had already done (and tested) it.

Comment: Protip: ggvG= will select every line in the file and autoformat

Comment: Whaledawg. you can even just gg=G and save a character. Its worth remembering you can action-motion most commands in vim

Comment: Love the shift-v + = shortcut. This is going to save me some headaches. Thanks a lot. How do I give more votes to you :)

Comment: WOW! simple & powerful!

Comment: If you want to format a whole paragraph at once, let's say a function or method, press `vip=`. `vip` will select the paragraph in visual line mode (from anywhere in the function) and `=` will set the indentation properly.

Note that `=` will set the indentation, not auto format the selected text as adding spaces before or after parenthesis, brackets, etc.

Comment: Even better, I just discovered `=ip` indents a paragraph directly (`=` -> indent, `i` -> inside, `p` -> paragraph)

Comment: Does anyone know of a way to set whether squiggly braces are on same line as if or below if?

Answer (score 16):

Enter normal mode in vim and then type

```
1GVG=
```

Comment: 1G - goes to first line;
V  - switches to visual mode;
G  - goes to end of file;
=  - auto format selected code;

Comment: `gg=G` is slighlty easier (less capslock)

Comment: Actually this command triggers the functionality in the indent script. It only reindents the code, no complete reformatting.

Comment: I would use `ggvG=` instead also for the record they are the same thing

Comment: `gg`: **Cursor to line N, default first line**

Answer (score 10):

## Format in PSR-2 style

For the new standard [Coding Style Guide PSR-2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) use the [PHP-CS-Fixer](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer).

There is a Vim plugin: [Vim-php-cs-fixer](https://github.com/stephpy/vim-php-cs-fixer)

#### How to install:

Install `PHP-CS-Fixer` (globally with `Composer`):

```
composer global require friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer
```

Then add the Vim plugin (`Pathogen`):

```
cd ~/.vim/bundle
git clone git@github.com:stephpy/vim-php-cs-fixer.git
```

Restart Vim.

### Default mapping:

```
<leader>pcd " For directory
<leader>pcf " For flie
```

Comment: To run **php-cs-fixer** automatically after the file is saved, add the following line in ~/.vimrc:

`autocmd BufWritePost *.php call PhpCsFixerFixFile()`

Comment: I get the error ```E117: Unknown function: php_cs_fixer#fix```

Comment: @Mahdimehrabi Same here, any luck?

Answer (score 8):

There is a vim plugin that enables formatting on your code from within vim. It's called vim-autoformat and you can read about it and download it here:

https://github.com/vim-autoformat/vim-autoformat

It integrates external code-formatting programs into vim. When this plugin is installed, you only have to install an external code formatter to get everything to work out of the box. It supports the php formatter **phpCB**, which is the best php formatter i've seen so far.

**UPDATE:** phpCB is not supported anymore, due to code breaking behaviour. However, vim's indentfile is always used as fallback, allowing you to at least indent your code when there's is no formatter available.

Answer (score 2):

The [vim website](http://vim.org) is not the easiest to navigate, but there is a wealth of chewy nougat center there.

For instance I found [this php indenting script](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1120) there. Give it a try.